# Deploying issue with play 2.1.2 app on jboss 7

Tags: playframework, jboss7.x, web-deployment, playframework-2.1

I am trying to deploy a play app on a JBoss AS 7.1.2, but I am having some troubles. When I try to deploy the app through the jboss-cli it fails with the error:

```
{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" =>         {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS0
14671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./playApp-" =>  "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in
service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./playApp-: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
```

I am compiling the war file with the play2-war-plugin version 1.0 and version of the servlet container 3.0.

Here it is the server log with the error:

```
12:11:11,867 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2)     JBAS015012: Started FileSystem
DeploymentService for directory D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
12:11:12,073 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001:  Failed to start service jboss.re
moting.server.remoting-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service  jboss.remoting.server.remoting-connector: JBAS017112: Address already in use: bind  /127.0.0.1:4447
    at  org.jboss.as.remoting.AbstractStreamServerService.start(AbstractStreamServerService.java:109)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpServer(NioXnioWorker.java:287)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamServer(XnioWorker.java:135)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionProvider$ProviderInterface.createServer(RemoteConnectionProvider.java:209)
    at org.jboss.as.remoting.AbstractStreamServerService.start(AbstractStreamServerService.java:101)
    ... 5 more

12:11:12,081 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1)     Error initializing endpoint:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind /127.0.0.1:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:190) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]

12:11:12,113 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.connector.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.connector.http: JBAS018007: Error starting web connector
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:271)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
Caused by: LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind /127.0.0.1:8080
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:985)
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267)
    ... 5 more

12:11:12,168 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
12:11:12,515 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
12:11:12,750 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.connector.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.connector.http: JBAS018007: Error starting web connector
  service jboss.remoting.server.remoting-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.remoting-connector: JBAS017112: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:4447

12:11:12,893 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
12:11:12,895 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 7272ms - Started 128 of 207 services (4 services failed or missing dependencies, 74 services are passive or on-demand)
12:15:13,519 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011942: Stopping OSGi Framework
12:15:13,562 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011503: Restored bootstrap log handlers
12:15:13,583 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] ARJUNA032018: Destroying TransactionManagerService
12:15:13,586 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] ARJUNA032014: Stopping transaction recovery manager
12:15:13,600 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" stopped in 99ms
```

Comment: You get a number of 'Address already in use' type errors. Try to kill all running java processes and start over. Have you tried putting your war file directly into deploy directory (JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments)?

Answer (score -1):

Restarting eclipse solved this error for me